# How to detect if a widget is shown or not in wxpython?

Tags: python, widget, wxpython

How can I know if a widget is shown or not?
"self.IsShown" is for window.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Widgets inherit from wx.Window so they have the IsShown method

```
import wx
from wx.lib import sized_controls


class TestFrame(sized_controls.SizedFrame):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(TestFrame, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        pane = self.GetContentsPane()
        self.btn = wx.Button(pane, label='Hide')
        self.btn.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.on_btn)
        self.btn_hidden = wx.Button(pane, label='Hidden?')

        self.s_txt = wx.StaticText(pane, label='Button shown: True')

    def on_btn(self, event):
        is_shown = not self.btn_hidden.IsShown()
        self.btn_hidden.Show(is_shown)
        self.s_txt.SetLabel('Button shown: {}'.format(is_shown))
        if is_shown:
            self.btn.SetLabel('Hide')
        else:
            self.btn.SetLabel('Show')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    wxapp = wx.App(False)
    main_app_frame = TestFrame(None)
    main_app_frame.Show()
    wxapp.MainLoop()
```